# how to make the code cleaner? (reset variables)

Tags: python-3.x

```
word = "hello"
string = word[0] + "_ _" + word[-1]
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
n = 10
```

I want to reinitialize the variables with the following variables via a function

```
word = "text"
string = word[0] + "_ _" + word[-1]
l1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
l2 = [2, 2, 2, 2]
n = 0
```

what I would do:

```
def reset(word, string, l1, l2, n):
    word = "text"
    string = word[0] + "_ _" + word[-1]
    l1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    l2 = [2, 2, 2, 2]
    n = 0
    return word, string, l1, l2, n

word = "hello"
string = word[0] + "_ _" + word[-1]
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
n = 10

(word, string, l1, l2, n) = reset(word, string, l1, l2, n)
```

there is a way to do the same thing more cleanly? (sry for my bad english)

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do, but your function will work exactly the same if you remove all the arguments from it and change it to just "reset()"

Comment: to be cleaner I usually save the functions in another file. i think that writing the functions in the same file as the program is not a very clean thing to do.

Comment: I think implementing this in class might look clean.